# Kendo grid datetime convert issue in IE

Tags: kendo-grid

Hi all~ I'm using Kendo grid to display date time column from server side Web API.

In Chrome, the result display as expected.But in IE, I encounter some problems:

In the response body, I get the data :

```
[{"SerialNO":43,"SurveyCyclesSN":null,"StartDateTime":"2016-12-21T00:00:00","EndDateTime":"2016-12-30T11:00:00"}]
```

In Chrome, Kendo grid convert UTC time to local time correctly:
[the correct value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdX9c.png)

But in IE, the datetime does not convert correctly:
[the wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnGjT.png)

Any advice for this problem? Thanks~

Comment: In which format you wan your output ?

Comment: Hi~ I use this code to do the format:

Comment: kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(StartDateTime), 'yyyy/MM/dd')

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
 new Date(kendo.toString("Fri Dec 30 2016 19:00:00 GMT+0800")) or

 new Date("Fri Dec 30 2016 19:00:00 GMT+0800")
```

it gives me =>

Fri Dec 30 2016 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

This is the code

```
 new Date(kendo.toString(StartDateTime))
```

Attaching image :
[image]

This is how your data is :
See the red dots. 
[image]

You should use better formatter like Newtonsoft json converter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to clarify the problem, I wrote some console to log the datetime value:

Comment: {
                    title: "&nbsp",
                    template: function (e) {

                        console.log('StartDateTime: ', e.StartDateTime);

                        console.log('kendo.parseDate: ', kendo.parseDate(e.StartDateTime));

                        console.log('kendo.toString: ',new Date(kendo.toString(e.StartDateTime,'yyyy/MM/dd')));}

Comment: In Chrome the StartDateTime is => Wed Dec 21 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time) ; in IE is => Wed Dec 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time), so the time zone seems convert correctly, but something wrong in the hour part. How can I fix this?

Comment: I am able to see same answer in both by running : console.log('kendo.parseDate: ', kendo.parseDate("Fri Dec 30 2016 19:00:00 GMT+0800") or console.log('kendo.parseDate: ', kendo.parseDate("2016-12-30T11:00:00")) Update your browser, I am using IE 11

Comment: I'm also using IE 11, so I don't know the root cause it is.Thanks anyway~

Comment: Not yet. Still try to find solution.

Comment: Here is my IE version:11.09600.18538, the problem is browser version?

Comment: I am getting correct output in IE I have same version of IE, what you are exactly trying to convert, give me the query

Comment: Here is Kendo grid column config: `columns: [
                {
                    field: "StartDateTime",
                    title: "{{ '起始日期' | translate }}",
                    template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(StartDateTime), 'yyyy/MM/dd')#"
                },
                {
                    field: "StartDateTime",
                    title: "{{ '起始時間' | translate }}",
                    template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(StartDateTime), 'HH:mm')#"
                },`

Comment: And in the backend service, I just wrote a Web API retrive data from SQL database.

Comment: give your data that you are using in your grid input, I have added image in my answer as viewed in IE

Comment: "SurveyCyclesSingle":[{"SerialNO":43,"SurveyCyclesSN":null,"StartDateTime":"2016-12-21T00:00:00","EndDateTime":"2016-12-30T11:00:00"}]

Comment: If you will write the data in console by hand then it gets converted easily. But, data you are getting from api is not correct or is not in correct format, it is carrying some special symbols with themselves, I have copied your data and pasted in console, I have uploaded an image , see how your data looks like in console, use proper formatter at your api end, Newtonsoft. JSOn converter. then try it again.